# Preserving a module's code splitting when importing it

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

I am using Webpack to build an NPM module. It has several modules inside it that are dynamically imported. In the production build step, this means it generates about 8 JavaScript files.

When you `npm install` the module, it only brings the build folder not the source files over.

The problem is I am trying to consume this NPM module into a different project that also uses Webpack. Even when I use the [`cacheGroups`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkscachegroups) functionality to target only my NPM module, it is rolling all of my build files into one file when I just want it to preserve what's already there.

This would be bad on its own because it removes code splitting - but it also doesn't work because the file is still trying to reach out to individual files that don't exist.

I want other projects to be able to easily get the benefit of code splitting that this NPM module offers (it has a huge effect on load times.) Is there an easy way to achieve this in the consuming project's Webpack configuration?

The only thing I can think of is to also provide the source files in the NPM module and point there as the entry.